# Jetty Spring Boot with session replication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, jetty-9

I am using spring boot 2.5.3 with Jetty 9.4.43.v20210629. I want to share the session across multiple nodes. In Jetty 9.4 there are lot of changes in session management. I want some reference materials for session replication (using JDBC / File system) with java configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session replication can be done using spring session with following storage options,

Hazlecast
Database
Redis
MongoDB

**spring.session.store-type** property should be used to decide the storage type. When multiple nodes / containers point to same storage it will share the session and no need to maintain a sticky session.

Need to add proper dependencies in pom.xml and add annotations when required (ex: @EnableJDBCHttpSession)

### sample application yaml changes.

### JDBC

```
spring:
    application.name: console-bs
    main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    profile: default
    session.store-type: jdbc
    session.jdbc.initialize-schema: always
    jpa.database: mysql
    jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/user
    datasource.username: user
    datasource.password: user1234#
    datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

### Redis

```
spring:
    application.name: console-bs
    main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    profile: default
    session.store-type: redis
    redis.host: redis
    redis.port: 6379
```

Comment: Posting the YAML in a code block would improve legibility greatly

Comment: Edited the answer to post the YAML in code block. Thanks